# Why is my Brother printer not printing fonts in a PDF correctly?

Tags: printing, fonts, pdf

I have a Brother HL-L2380DW printer, which is connected wirelessly to my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS desktop. Typically, I can print from it without issue, but presently, it is not printing a certain PDF correctly.

If I view the PDF in Evince, the fonts display correctly. When I print, however, all the embedded fonts fail to render, and instead are printed in a Courier-like monospace font.

I have installed all of the fonts embedded in the document. They still fail to render correctly when printing.

This is the output of `pdffonts file.pdf`:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
CFSPKS+ACaslonPro-Regular            Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      17  0
CFSPKS+ACaslonPro-Regular            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     18  0
NTVBOE+Geogrotesque-SemiBold         Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      21  0
GGSUWO+ACaslonPro-Italic             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      31  0
GGSUWO+ACaslonPro-Italic             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     32  0
IJBFJW+Geogrotesque-Bold             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      38  0
```

When I previewed the PDF in Firefox, then printed from there, the fonts rendered correctly but printed at a low resolution—the image quality was "fuzzy". That was not ideal for me, so I'd like to figure out how to print from Evince so these fonts render.

I'd appreciate any help to troubleshoot and solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Did you install any printer drivers for your printer? If not, does this answer your question? [pdf font mangling on printing mixed results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042347/pdf-font-mangling-on-printing-mixed-results)

Comment: I had no luck with that solution. When I open the "Change Driver" window, a dialog pops up informing me that the application is searching for drivers, and it hangs there. The application freezes and stops responding.

Comment: Search this site for **brother printer driver**. As these answers indicate, you may need to download and follow the installation instructions.